# How can I test Angular4 Observables service method through MockBackend and FakeAsync

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine, observable

I have Angular4 service method which returns Observables. I have to use FakeAsync and tick() for unit testing. Can I use Mockbackend to mock webapi data, if I want to test fakeAsync and tick() for Observables? Is there any restriction of using MockBackend with FakeAsync for Observables?

is there any complete writeup on this subject? is there any sample code for the same? Sample code must cover 1.MockBackend 2. observables 3. fakeAsync 4.tick()

My idea is, I shouldn't use XHRBackend with FakeAsync. is my idea correct? It will be extremely helpful if you clarify this

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use MockBackend Provider in Angular4

You can found a sample code here:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Comment: this is not the code/ approach I am looking for. code should cover all of these: 1.MockBackend 2. observables 3. fakeAsync 4.tick()  .                          you have to send me correct code.